# Como poner div, dentro de otro div, que quede en medio y que el texto dentro de este esté en el medio tambien. HTML y Css

Tags: html, css

¿Cómo puedo crear un `div` dentro de otro `div` y que este se posicione en el medio?

El div que quiero poner es el `#left` y el `#right`
Adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi código actual es este:

```css
body {
  background: #232323;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: #02ff06;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.1;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#colorToGuess {
  font-size: 200%;
}

.square {
  width: 30%;
  background: purple;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
  border-radius: 15%;
  transition: background 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.6s;
}

.colorContainer {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5% auto;
}

.square:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px white;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s;
}

#stripe {
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.selected {
  background: #02ff06;
  color: white;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #02ff06;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: inherit;
  outline: none !important;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #02ff06;
}

#msg {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
}

.counter {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>RGB Guessing Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="RGBGuess.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>THE GREAT
    <br>
    <span id="colorToGuess">Color</span>
    <br> Guessing Game</h1>
  <div id="stripe">
    <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
    <span id="msg"></span>
    <button id="easyBtn">Easy</button>
    <button id="hardBtn" class="selected">Hard</button>
  </div>
  <div id="left">
    <div class="counter">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div class="colorContainer">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="RGBGuess.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres centrar todo dentro de un `div` puedes usar la magia de [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex), con las propiedades `justify-content: center; align-items: center;` de esta manera:

```css
body {
  background: #232323;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#colorToGuess {
  font-size: 200%;
}

.square {
  width: 30%;
  background: purple;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
  border-radius: 15%;
  transition: background 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.6s;
}

.colorContainer {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5% auto;
}

.square:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px white;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s;
}

#left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  min-height: 15rem;
  background-color: #00F;
}

#right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  min-height: 15rem;
  background-color: #0F0;
}

.counter {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <div class="counter">
    <span>0</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="right">
  <div>
    <p>HOLA</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="colorContainer">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  body {
background: #232323;
margin: 0;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
color: white;
text-align: center;
background: #02ff06;
margin: 0;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: 1.1;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#colorToGuess {
font-size: 200%;
}

.square {
width: 30%;
background: purple;
margin: 4.5px;
padding-bottom: 30%;
float: left;
border-radius: 15%;
transition: background 0.6s;
-webkit-transition: background 0.6s;
-moz-transition: background 0.6s;
}

.colorContainer {
width: 50%;
margin: 5% auto;

}

.square:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 3px white;
transition: all 0.1s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s;
}

#stripe {
background: white;
text-align: center;
height: 30px;
width: 100%;
}

.selected {
background: #02ff06;
color: white;
}

button {
border: none;
background: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
height: 100%;
font-weight: 700;
color: #02ff06;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: inherit;
outline: none !important;
transition: all 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
color: white;
background-color: #02ff06;
}

#msg {
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
width: 20%;
text-align: center;
}

#left {
float: left;
width: 25%;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 250px;
}

#right {
float: right;
width: 25%;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 250px;
}

.counter {
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
margin: auto;
background-color: red;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50%;
}
.counter2 {
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
margin: auto;
background-color: red;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>THE GREAT
      <br>
      <span id="colorToGuess">Color</span>
      <br> Guessing Game</h1>
    <div id="stripe">
      <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
      <span id="msg"></span>
      <button id="easyBtn">Easy</button>
      <button id="hardBtn" class="selected">Hard</button>
    </div>
    <div id="left">
      <div class="counter">
        <span>0</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div class="counter2">
        <span>0</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colorContainer">
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="RGBGuess.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: No solo coloques el código, trata de explicar que hiciste para que sea aceptada como respuesta válida.

Answer (score 0):

Si mi div que quiero centrar tiene una medida fija uso esto:

```
div{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
width:500px;
height:500px;
margin:-250px auto 0;
}
```

Ese es ideal para por ejemplo: ventanas de notificaciones o menus.